# Simple design for bidirectional current thought a coil

Tags: current, coil

I have a coil made of a spiral PCB trace, with a measure inductance of about 20uH and resistance of about 10 ohms.
I want to be able to run, say, 200-300ma through the coil in either direction (the trace is thick enough to handle the current). Switching between directions is slow, say 10-20Hz.
I have an array of such coils (probably will use a shift register to reduce GPIO count).
I would prefer to have a simple design, with a single 5v or 12v supply.
What would be the best way to implement this? Specifically how can I easily and cheaply control the direction of current flow? MOSFETs? Buffers? In what configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limited to a single supply voltage, the classic approach is called an H-bridge.  Four saturating switch devices at the four ends of a capital-H, two pulling up and two pulling down, with the load in the cross-bar position.  Of course, there are options.

If you can stand the driving voltage loss, two power opamps can do this, a saturating variation of an audio power amplifier topology called BTL - Bridge-Tied Load.

If the current were lower, two 555's could act as half-bridges.  Intersil has a long line of bridge driver chips for things like motors and switching power supplies.  Some companies have half-bridge and full-bridge drivers with big-enough MOSFETs built in.

https://images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=AwrE19fdrVFiZxUAEEZXNyoA;_ylu=Y29sbwNiZjEEcG9zAzEEdnRpZAMEc2VjA3BpdnM-?p=H-bridge+driver+circuit&fr2=piv-web